# Costs for swapping car lease

Tags: united-states, car, auto-leasing

I'm considering an auto lease swap, for which the online sites (swapalease, leasetrader) have info on the *number of months remaining* and *cost per month* etc. However, after some research I realized that many cars are quite distant and need to be shipped with insurance. There is also more confusing terminology of requiring a down payment (does this reduce monthly payments or its in addition?) and apparently some fees for using the websites.

What are the other costs involved in lease transfer, and how do I estimate the total expenditure? I understand that some things like shipping are variable, but hopefully there are ways to get a ballpark estimate.

Comment: It is an awful idea to buy a car site unseen, lease trade or otherwise.

Comment: @quid The idea is to basically have a low-cost long term (< 1 year) rental, probably of an electric car, with no plans to buy it at lease end. Lease vehicles have regular dealer maintenance so I'm assuming it works well, and I'm not going for a sporty car which may have hidden damage from racing etc.